# Why redis pubsub working is independent of database?

Tags: redis

I am newbie to Redis and trying to understand concept of Redis PubSub.

```
Step- 1:
root@01a623a828db:/data# redis-cli -n 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> subscribe foo
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "foo"
3) (integer) 1
```

In 1st step, subscribed database 1

```
Step- 2:
root@01a623a828db:/data# redis-cli -n 4
127.0.0.1:6379[4]> publish foo 2
(integer) 1
```

In 2nd step, published message on database 4

```
Step- 3:
root@01a623a828db:/data# redis-cli -n 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> subscribe foo
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
..........................................

1) "message"
2) "foo"
3) "2"
```

In 3rd step, on database 1 got the message which was published on database 4 in 2nd Step.

I tried to find out the reason behind it but I found same answer everywhere- **"Pub/Sub has no relation to the key space. It was made to not interfere with it on any level, including database numbers. Publishing on db 10, will be heard by a subscriber on db 1. If you need scoping of some kind, prefix the channels with the name of the environment (test, staging, production)- This is as per official documentation of Redis PubSub."**

Ques-

1. Why redis pubsub working architecture is independent of database?
2. How to implement "If you need scoping of some kind, prefix the channels with the name of the environment (test, staging, production)"?
3. "Publishing on db 10, will be heard by a subscriber on db 1."- It is not inline with statement 
   `It was made to not interfere with it on any level, including database numbers.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it's a matter of design choice really.
2. If you need scoping, you can always prefix the pattern. eg: pattern `productupdate` on test env will be watched via `test:productupdate` and on staging env, it will be `staging:productupdate`
3. It seems to inline well with the statement. the database number doesn't matter here.